# How to plot a linear regression to a double logarithmic R plot?

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, logarithm

I have the following data:

```
someFactor = 500
x = c(1:250)
y = x^-.25 * someFactor
```

which I show in a double logarithmic plot:

```
plot(x, y, log="xy")
```

Now I "find out" the slope of the data using a linear model:

```
model = lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
model
```

which gives:

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ log(x))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       log(x)  
      6.215       -0.250
```

Now I'd like to plot the linear regression as a red line, but abline does not work:

```
abline(model, col="red")
```

What is the easiest way to add a regression line to my plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lines(log(x), exp(predict(model, newdata=list(x=log(x)))) ,col="red")
```

The range of values for x plotted on the log-scale and for log(x) being used as the independent variable are actually quite different. This will give you the full range:

```
lines(x, exp(predict(model, newdata=list(x=x))) ,col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: I predicted only two values (one close to zero, and one very large one). Then the line is not only between the smallest and the largest value in the graph, but goes beyond them.

Answer (score 4):

Your line *is* being plotted, you just can't see it in the window because the values are quite different.  What is happening when you include the `log='xy'` argument is that the space underneath the plot (so to speak) is being distorted (stretched and/or compressed), nonetheless, the original numbers are still being used.  (Imagine you are plotting these points by hand on graph paper; you are still marking a point where the faint blue graph lines for, say, (1,500) cross, but the graph paper has been continuously stretched such that the lines are not equally spaced anymore.)  On the other hand, your model is using the transformed data.

You need to make your plot with the same transformed data as your model, and then simply re-mark your axes in a way that will be sufficiently intuitively accessible.  This is a first try:

```
plot(log(x), log(y), axes=FALSE, xlab="X", ylab="Y")
box()
axis(side=1,     at=log(c(1,2, 10,20, 100,200)), 
             labels=c(    1,2, 10,20, 100,200))
axis(side=2,     at=log(c(125,135, 250,260, 350, 500)), 
             labels=c(    125,135, 250,260, 350, 500))
abline(model, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I hate R,... there seems to be no way to add a regression line, without manipulating the original data. Then I also have to minipulate the data for the error bars (`errbar`) and the nice looking axis ticks (`eaxis`), since this is also not implemented by default.

Comment: I think this is a bug in R imho

Answer (score 3):

Instead of transforming the axes, plot the log-transformed `x` and `y`.

```
plot(log(x), log(y))
abline(model, col="red")
```